# How to access PHPUnit in anywhere WIndows

Tags: php, windows, phpunit

Hi i have installed phpUnit to my computer ,I can run `phpunit` in command line inside my **C:/xampp/php** location, but outside of that I can not use **phpunit**

How can I have access to PHPUnit from anywhere in windows?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a .bat file somewhere on your PATH (so that it will run anywhere) that references both php and phpunit by their full path

Comment: Not too sure, but try adding it to your PATH

Answer (score 0):

Add it to the PATH environment variable. It vary slightly between windows version but should be around the system settings.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have installed phpunit inside your php installation folder, C:/xampp/php

Ensure that C:/xampp/php is added to windows environment.

You may open computer properties and find environment variables and edit or add PATH

Usually there may be previous entries. So add a semi colon and add C:/xampp/php to environment

By doing so both php and phpunit are in environment.

Assuming you have a batch file phpunit.bat

If the batch file has some path issue you may edit it for paths.

You can find a very detailed step by step instructions in the given url

http://answers.waytoedu.com/10/how-to-set-up-phpunit-available-anywhere-in-windows

Regards,
Najeem M Illyas